# How to check laravel 6 route that doesn't exist?

Tags: routes, laravel-routing, laravel-6

I have similar code at my local and my dev-server. When I execute 'php artisan route:list', both of them show me these errors:
first: `Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException  : Target class [App\Http\Controllers\API\PersonalInformationController] does not exist.`

and then second times:
`Illuminate\Contracts\Container\BindingResolutionException  : Target class [App\Http\Controllers\API\Ecommerce\ProductController] does not exist.`

In 1st error, I got PersonalInformationController with wrong namespace. Corrected, push, and my local show no errs. But in my dev-server, it still show second errors. But there are no call for App\Http\Controllers\API\Ecommerce\ProductController at any my routes files.

I've done these:

1. composer dump-autoload
2. php artisan config:clear
3. php artisan config:cache

What did I missed?

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan route:cache`? That'll clear and re-load your routes.

Comment: Thank's alot! This is work!